# How to recognize tab space in my search string while using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

My input file is `.h` file containing

```
#define __CON__       2
#define __CON_MINOR__ 23

#define __CON_PREREQ(maj, min) \
        ((__CON__ << 16) + __CON_MINOR__ >= ((maj) << 16) + (min))
```

I need to search for `__CON_` which prints out 2 and 23 as 2.23. There's a tab space after `CON__`. I'm using the command

```
awk '/__CON__/&&'/__CON_MINOR/' {print $3;}' features.h
```

getting a wrong output for this.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
awk '/__CON__/ {con=$3;} /__CON_MINOR__/ {print con "." $3; exit;}' features.h
```